# Read yml file and convert it to HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, java-8

In this example, I am reading whole YML file and trying to convert it  to HashMap, but by default it uses linkedHashMap, but that doesn't give flexibility to operate on it. Any quick help on this?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.example.MainApp.lambda$main$0(MainApp.java:22)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at com.example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="yamlMap" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlMapFactoryBean">
        <property name="resources" value="classpath:application.yaml"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="configReader" class="com.example.ConfigReader">
        <property name="yamlMap" ref="yamlMap" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

application.yml

```
priority:
  1:
    type: 'P'
    country: 'US'
    countryFriend: ['UK','AG']
  2:
    type: 'P'
    country: 'IN'
    countryFriend: ['UK','AG']
  3:
    type: 'P'
    country: 'PO'
    countryFriend: ['NL']
  4:
    type: 'E'
    country: 'KN'
    countryFriend: ['DN']
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Map propsBean = context.getBean("yamlMap", Map.class);

        Map<Integer, AppConfig> configMap = (Map<Integer, AppConfig>) propsBean.get("priority");

        Map<Integer, String> mapOfPriorityAndTypeAndCountry = configMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().getType() + ":" + e.getValue().getCountry()));
        System.out.println(mapOfPriorityAndTypeAndCountry);
```

Map<String, AppConfig> mapOfCountryTypeAndValue = configMap.entrySet()
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getValue().getCountry() + e.getValue().getType(), e -> e.getValue()));
System.out.println(mapOfCountryTypeAndValue);
}
}

[image]

Comment: A LinkedHashMap extends a HashMap (both in functionality and in literal class inheritance), so in most contexts where you need a HashMap, you can just use the LinkedHashMap you were given. Can you elaborate on why you specifically need a normal HashMap?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the code that you're trying (and what the errors are), or an exact representation of the map that you *do* want from this data; it's not clear exactly where you're stuck from that text description alone. It sounds like the issue is you wanting a structural map change, not just linkedhashmap vs hashmap, so the situation isn't very clear.

Comment: As already said, a LinkedHashMap is a HashMap. you’re asking what you think is the problem, not what is it that you want to do.

Comment: @nanofarad - I've updated the whole questions, please see if you can answer

Comment: I can't make sense of all of these imports or how they relate to the central task at hand (also traveling and on phone), but consider avoiding the "fancy" functional/streams approach, and just write a straightforward loop that iterates through the map you have, and calls `put` on the map you're filling in, with the structure that makes sense for you

Comment: @nanofarad - Hey I am trying to use it in normal ways also, but unable to use it and it keeps giving me the ClassCastExceptions

Comment: The exceptions are coming from casting the String keys to Integer, not from anything relating to LinkedHashMap vs HashMap. Yaml does support int keys, though I think many parsers will treat them as string by default (citation needed). Your debugger view shows the keys as bracketed, like `[1]` — is that how they are in the yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve using below solution. Now I can create multiple combinations and all are working fine. Hope somebody will find it helpful.

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        HashMap propsBean = context.getBean("yamlMap", HashMap.class);

        HashMap<String, AppConfig> priorityMap = (HashMap<String, AppConfig>) propsBean.get("priority");
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(priorityMap.keySet());

        HashMap priority = (HashMap) propsBean.get("priority");

        Map<Integer, AppConfig> MAP = new HashMap<>();
        for (String k: keys) {
            HashMap map = (HashMap) priority.get(k);
            Integer key = Integer.parseInt(k.replace("[","").replace("]",""));

            MAP.put(key, new AppConfig((String) map.get("type"),(String) map.get("country"),(List<String>) map.get("countryFriend")));
        }
        System.out.println(MAP);
    }
}
```